# How do I use a date reference on 1 sheet to use as a place to paste data on multiple other sheets but copied on same sheet as to be pasted

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that needs daily updating of 72 different sheets. I want to use todays date located on "SheetList" (I1) as a search parameter to determine where data gets pasted. The data is located in the same range on each sheet (G2:G365) I then have a column on every sheet that lists the date range I am using (L2:L145). When the date is matched in (L2:145) I need to transpose all the cells copied in range (G2:G365) starting in column M next to the correct date. The data is copied and pasted on the same sheet but I need to do it over all 72 sheets. I already have the macro to copy the data and put it in the (G2:G365) range but I am stuck on figuring out how to locate the date in column L then offset to column M and transpose the cells. Not all copied cells have data but that should not be an issue as I want to copy and paste the whole range.

So in a nutshell the date listed in cell I1 on "SheetList"

copy data located on every sheet (G2:G365)

match date from cell "SheetList" (I1) to correct row of (L2:145)

Paste values (Numbers not text) into columns (M:NL) beside correct date

I would prefer to use sheet codes vs sheet names as well.

I have found many different scenarios but they all copy data to a different sheets, not the same one, and nothing seems look do an index match type function to determine where to put the data. I am new to VBA and have read a ton of conflicting ways to get info but nothing includes searching for where to place it.

```
Sub AAA_AllDailyUpdates()
'
' AAA_AllDailyUpdates Macro
'
Sheets("VsRPI1-25-1st").Select
            Range("F2:F365").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("G2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Sheets("VsRPI1-25-2nd").Select
           Range("F2:F365").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("G2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Sheets("VsRPI1-25HomeFinal").Select
            Range("F2:F365").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("G2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

End Sub

```
    Sub Transpose()
    Sheets("VsRPI1-25Final").Select
Range("G2:G365").Select
Selection.Copy
    Range("M94").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True

Sheets("VsRPI1-25-1st").Select
Range("G2:G365").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
    Range("M94").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
```

End Sub

In the Transpose macro this is the line that I know needs to lookup the current date on "SheetList" (I1) but I am having trouble figuring out how to do the reference cell then offset into column "M"

```
    Range("M94").Select
```

Comment: This is a good post in terms of trying to tell us what you would like. However, what have you tried? Have you tried to record a macro and then learning from there?

Comment: Have you tried [Find Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) ?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you have for "macro to copy the data and put it in the (G2:G365) range"?

Comment: Code added but only for a couple sheets. Yes I am learning VBA. I have been using excel for years and have gotten quite good at writing formulas to get my data arranged and displayed how I want it but the time it takes is getting out of hand. Using VBA to automate my data copying will greatly reduce my hands on time that can be used elsewhere. I still need to pull data from different sources but that will be difficult to figure out but by saving the time copying I can dedicate more time to learning how to do it,

Comment: I have been trying to use the Find Method but I keep getting errors, I do think that is the way to go and using Dim to set my (I1) cell as a reference so I do not need to write out the code for every worksheet change.